# is there a way to print a variable of type char** in gdb?

Tags: gdb, remote-debugging

Is there a way to print variables that are of type char** in gdb?
I mean, say if there was a variable `int length = 17;` in the .c file and in gdb, typing p length will show length = 17. However, if its of char**, is there any way to print it and see the characters/strings inside that variable? Been searching on google but couldn't find any info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, if its of char**, is there any way to print it and see the characters/strings inside that variable?

There are *no* characters / strings inside that variable.

What you are probably asking is: can I print the string that is pointed to by `*var`, in which case either `print *var` or `print var[0]` would do.